# Python: mod_rewrite-like function for bottle.py

Tags: python, bottle

I have an existing Python application which servers a bunch of files via a Bottle.py service.

Now I have to change the path the server should react to.
The obvious way would be to change the `@route` statement and prepend the new path to each route.

But I got the constraint that **the old path should keep on working** for a while.
As the server should react to the old requests, too, I would have to replicate each route-statement in order to have it once with the old and the new path.

So, straightforward it would be a change from:

```py
@route('/somefile')
def doSomeStuff():
```

to:

```py
@route('/somefile')
@route('/newpath/somefile')
def doSomeStuff():
```

But as there are a lot of routes and I don't want to mess with all the code, I am searching for an elegant way to process the requests **before** the routing happens.

Is there any way to hook into the routing process?

---

My current approach is to serve a 301 to the browser, but I don't like this solution as it increases the number of requests and changes the user's URLs.

```py
#Serve a 301 (hope the browsers remember it for a session at least)
@route('/newpath<path:path>')
def redirectNewToOld(path):
    if len(path) == 0:                         #Catch the lazy typers
        path = '/'
    redirect(path, code=301)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I wrote my own mod_rewrite for bottle.
Code can also be found on **[GitHub](https://github.com/Nippey/bottle/commit/5586f811ddaccc77b03d508a8be4a4ac70f3a2aa)**

### Changes:

(Based on fork created today, Oct 29, 2012)

**In** `class Bottle(object):`
**@Lines 754ff, one addition:**

```
def _handle(self, environ):
    try:
        environ['bottle.app'] = self
+       url_rewrite.apply(environ)    #Added mod_rewrite
        request.bind(environ)
        response.bind()
        route, args = self.router.match(environ)
        environ['route.handle'] = route
        environ['bottle.route'] = route
        environ['route.url_args'] = args
        return route.call(**args)
```

**Added at the bottom**

```
###############################################################################
# Nippey #### 29.10.2012 #### mod_rewrite #####################################
###############################################################################
# This modification to bottly.py allows the application of rewrite rules to 
# requests _before_ they are processed by the routing system

class UrlRewriteException(BottleException):
    """ This is a base class for all rewrite related exceptions """

class UrlRewrite():
    """ This class processes every URL before is is passed to the routing system 
    In case one of the included rewrite rules matches the URL, the URL will be modified.
    New rules can be added via the .addRule(str, str, bool) method.
    For each requested URL, the method apply will be called with the environ variable as parameter.
    """
    
    def __init__(self):
        """ Initiates the rules variable """
        print("UrlRewrite init.")
        self.rules = []
    
    def addRule(self, match, replace, final=False):
        """ Add a new rule.
        match:   Regular expression to search for. Can be a string or a compiled regular expression
        replace: Replacement string. May use backreferences.
        final:   If a rule with <final=True> matches the URL, the evaluation will be stopped afterwards
        """
        print("UrlRewrite addRule.")
        if type(match) is not str and type(replace) is not str:
            raise UrlRewriteException
        pattern = re.compile(match)
        self.rules.append({'pattern':pattern, 'repl':replace, 'final':bool(final)})
    
    def apply(self, environ):
        """ Test a URL for a match of one of the saved rules and rewrite it if required
        environ: Environmental variable created by bottle on each request. Contains the PATH_INFO 
                 information, modification will happen with the reference to this variable.
        returns: Returns true if a rewrite has been executed. Not used by the main program (yet)
                 Original path will still be available as PATH_INFO_ORIGINAL in the environ variable
        """
        print("UrlRewrite apply.")
        rewritten = False
        url = environ['PATH_INFO']
        for rule in self.rules:             #Try to alppy each of the rules
            (url, noSubs) = rule['pattern'].subn(rule['repl'], url)
            if noSubs > 0:
                rewritten = True
                if rule['final']:
                    break
        if rewritten:
            environ['PATH_INFO_ORIGINAL'] = environ['PATH_INFO']
            environ['PATH_INFO'] = url
            return True
        return False

    """ EXAMPLES:
    
    #Backreferences may be used by the replacement string
    from bottle import url_rewrite
    url_rewrite.addRule("^/he(l*)o", r"/by\1e", False)
    #Input:  "/hello/test_hello" 
    #Output: "/bye/test_hello"
    
    #All matching occurences will be replaced
    from bottle import url_rewrite
    url_rewrite.addRule("hello", "bye", False)
    #Input:  "/hello/test_hello" 
    #Output: "/bye/test_bye"
    
    #Rules will be applied in successive order
    from bottle import url_rewrite
    url_rewrite.addRule("hello", "hi", False)
    url_rewrite.addRule("hi", "bye", False)
    #Input:  "/hello/test_hello" 
    #Output: "/bye/test_bye"
    
    #Rules won't be re-applied from the start if one rule matches
    from bottle import url_rewrite
    url_rewrite.addRule("hi", "bye", False)
    url_rewrite.addRule("hello", "hi", False)
    #Input:  "/hello/test_hello" 
    #Output: "/hi/test_hi"
    
    #After applying a rule with <final> set to True, the evaluation will be finished
    from bottle import url_rewrite
    url_rewrite.addRule("hello", "hi", True)
    url_rewrite.addRule("hi", "bye", False)
    #Input:  "/hello/test_hello" 
    #Output: "/hi/test_hi"
    """
# END class UrlRewrite

url_rewrite = UrlRewrite()
# END ## mod_rewrite ## Nippey
```

I've sent a pull request, but here it is in case it won't be pulled in. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Two things come to mind, but none of them are as nice as simply having a nginx in front of your webapp. The first one is using a middleware class to rewrite `PATH_INFO` - there is [WSGIRewrite](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/WSGIRewrite/) for that, but the general idea is:

```
from bottle import route, run, app

@route('/oldpath/somefile')
def index(): return 'Hello'

class RewriteMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    def __call__(self, env, res):
        path = env['PATH_INFO']
        if path.startswith('/newpath'):
            env['PATH_INFO'] = path.replace('/newpath', '/oldpath', 1)

        return self.app(env, res)

app = RewriteMiddleware(app())
run(app)
```

Alternatively, you could use [explicit routing](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/routing.html#explicit-routing-configuration), but this takes away some of bottle's charm:

```
from bottle import run, route

def index(): return 'Hello'

routes = (
    ('/oldpath/hello', 'GET', index),
    ('/oldpath/world', ['GET', 'POST'], index),
    )

def setup_routing():
    for path, method, handler in routes:
        if path.startswith('/oldpath'):
            newpath = path.replace('/oldpath', '/newpath', 1)
            route(newpath, method, handler)

        route(path, method, handler)

setup_routing()
run()
```

---

After rereading your question, it seems that the second option is a no go, since it involves modifying a lot of code. You could however iterate though all existing routes and add new ones:

```
for route in bottle.default_app[0].routes:
    if route.rule.startswith(...):
        bottle.route(..., route.call)
```

Comment: +1 Thank you very much for your answer! Finally I wrote some code myself which made me feel most content ;)

Comment: Just got feedback from the developer: A WSGIMiddleware would be his solution, too! So another virtual +1 for you! I'll stick to my solution as it still fits my needs the best way.

Comment: That's great. Did you have any luck with `WSGIRewrite` btw? It seems pretty nice, even if it hasn't been updated in a while. Keep in mind that wsgi middlewares are reusable between frameworks, so even if your code doesn't make it into bottle, it might be useful to someone else. Consider making it into a gist, as gists have a bit more visibility than a random commit in a closed pull request. Cheers.

Comment: It is an already declined pull request ;) I will definitely try WSGI next time I have some more minutes left for it!